# Need to force Xcode 5 to not use wildcard provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to use the new Automatic Configuration in Xcode 5 and it seems that when I run builds on my iPhone it is downloading the wildcard provisioning profile and using that to run the app. This is no good because my app uses push notifications and the wildcard will not have the correct entitlements to register for push notifications.

Is there a way to specify to use the provisioning profile for the qualified app id so I can test push notifications?

Strategies I have considered:

- Delete wildcard app id - You cannot do this
- Delete wildcard provisioning profile - Xcode will recreate the wildcard provisioning profile
- Specify the provisioning profile explicitly in the target's build settings

  1. I don't know how to determine the explicit name with Xcode 5. I could download and open the profile in a text editor, but that can't possibly be the right way to do this
  2. If I specify the provisioning profile, I will need to update it every time a new profile is generated (add a new device, profile expires, signing certificate expires). This defeats the purpose of automatic configuration.
- I've poked around Xcode looking for such a setting and haven't seen anything useful
- I have followed the steps [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW34) (for configuring Push Notifications) and when I refresh my provisioning profiles they are not updated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xcode was not downloading the provisioning profiles because it did not find any app id MATCHES. It did not find any matches because the capabilities in the "Certificates, Identifiers, Devices" website did not match the capabilities listed in the project in Xcode. Because the app identifier has In-App Purchase and Game Center enabled on the website but once I enabled it in the project it automatically downloaded the relevant provisioning profiles.

Hope this helps someone else.